# Issue with Button with Image or ImageButton in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to use a Button with an image instead of text. I have tried using a Button with an ImageSource and an ImageButton. Neither display the image, only a grey rectangle. I copied the XAML directly from the ImageButtonDemoPage.xaml in the ButtonDemos and also the XAML for using an image on a Button from the documentation. I show the code below along with a screen shot of the result. 
I have the image in the Resources/drawable folder as well as the Resources/drawable-hdpi folder as seen in the second screenshot. All images have their Build Action set to AndroidResource.
I have run out of ideas on what could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
'''

```
            </controls:UpcomingPaymentsView>
            <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <!--<Button>
                    <Button.ImageSource>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                            <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="MonkeyFace.png" />
                            <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/MonkeyFace.png" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Button.ImageSource>
                </Button>-->
                <ImageButton Source="MonkeyFace.png" 
                    WidthRequest="72"
                    HeightRequest="72"
                    FlexLayout.AlignSelf="Center"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                    Aspect="AspectFit">
                </ImageButton>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
```

'''
[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, please set the `Aspect="Fill"` in `ImageButton`, if it could show the image correctly. Then, my `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package version is 4.5.0.495, it could show the image correctly. Here is my test image and running result. https://imgur.com/a/9edlgE2

Comment: I updated my Xamarin.Forms package to the latest and that alone appears to have solved the problem. I've used various values for the Aspect and all seem to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: I will move the comments to answer. And please accept it as answer it will help others who have similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please set Aspect=Fill for the ImageButton, if you can see the image is displayed correctly, it could exclude the issue with image.

Then I test it in Xamarin Forms 4.5.0.495, ImageButton could show image normally, you could update your Xamarin Forms nuget packages to the latest or to 4.5.0.495